# Carousel for Twitter Bootstrap not working in IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I have a ready Carousel in Twitter Bootstrap that works in all browsers except in IE. Do you have guys have any idea, what change I can incur to make this work in IE :-

```
        <div class="module colored home-offerings primary-two-background">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span6">
                    <div class="arrow arrow-left hidden-phone"></div>
                    <div class="arrow arrow-right hidden-phone"></div>
                    <div class="content-container">
                        <h1 id="num-offerings"></h1>
                        <h2>offerings</h2>
                        <div class="dot-markers-home-offerings hidden-phone"></div>
                        <div id="swipe-container-home-offerings">
                            <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="solution-preview" value="primary-two-background">
                                            <a href="/Index/offerings/teliscope/">
                                                <h2>Telescope</h2>
                                            </a>
                                            <p>
                                                wjlwj lajsk djiowj alisdjlawij ealwijdlasjdlkjwijw lj dlkasdj ladjhdjs duhasjdah sduhwun ajsda                                                
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="solution-preview" value="primary-five-background">
                                            <a href="/Index/offerings/objective-health/">
                                                <h2>Objective Test</h2>
                                            </a>
                                            <p>Easd  akjsdhajk kjh jsh uiwhusjh uhwjh kah jsdka oijw jla iwjlajl sajsld jaslda skdjas j lwkjalsdasd.  </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>

                                    </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="find-a-solution">
                            <a class="visible-desktop" href="/Index/offerings/"><img class="light" src="/Index/images/see-more.png" /></a> 
                            <a class="hidden-desktop" href="/Index/offerings/"><img class="light" src="/Index/images/see-more-small-light.png" /></a> 
                            <a class="visible-desktop" href="/Index/offerings/"><img class="dark" src="/Index/images/see-more-dark.png" /></a> 
                            <a class="hidden-desktop" href="/Index/offerings/"><img class="dark" src="/Index/images/see-more-dark-small.png" /></a> 
                            <a href="/Index/offerings/"><h3>FIND AN OFFERING</h3></a>
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear: both"></div>
                        <div class="mobile-page-indicator visible-phone" id="num-offerings-page-indicator"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row visible-phone small-spacer"></div>
```

Comment: were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Put `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your document